# Бесконечный фоновый процесс в Android

Tags: java, android

Пишу программу на Android (дистанционное управление техникой).
Возникли проблемы с таймером (в конкретное время должно включаться и выключаться).
Как реализовать чтобы в фоне крутилась проверка?

Comment: Почитайте про класс Service (службы) https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services?hl=ru

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Читал, но не понял как сделать проверку в while(true)

Comment: Не надо добавлять метку android-studio. Она к вопросу не относится.

Comment: в сервисе крутите handler через секунду